# MySQL default value using another column

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
-------------
| id | date |
-------------
```

Now i need to add column "week", so is it possible to add column like

```
alter table `a` add column `week` INT(6) not null default DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y%v')
```

?

Comment: Why not try it? Then if you have an error or issue then ask the question.

Comment: You must use Trigger for this kind of functionality https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment above about using a trigger, is the way to go on this but doesn't elaborate on why you can't do it. So, from the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html) ...

> The DEFAULT value clause in a data type specification indicates a
>   default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must
>   be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means,
>   for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be
>   the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception
>   is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for TIMESTAMP
>   and DATETIME columns.